# Firestore: update specific element of an array

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a 2 players game. The structure of the document is this:

```
{
 status: string,
 create_by: string,
 players: [
  {
   id: string,
   time: int
  },
  {
   id: string,
   time: int
  } 
 ]
}
```

To create the session I do this:

```
Future<String> createGameSession() async {
    final user = AuthProvider().getUser();
    final sessionRef = await _firestore.collection('game_sessions').add({
      'created_by': user.uid,
      'status': 'open',
      'players': [
        {
          'id': user.uid,
        }
      ],
    });
    gameSessionId = sessionRef.id;
    return sessionRef.id;
  }
```

And when second player joins:

```
Future<void> addPlayerGameSession() async {
    final user = AuthProvider().getUser();
    await _firestore.collection('game_sessions').doc(gameSessionId).update({
      'status': 'closed',
      'players': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
        {
          'id': user.uid,
        }
      ]),
    });
  }
```

In the UI, users can stop a timer so when this happens, I need to update document. Here is where I have the problem of not being able to update just the document I need. I have to update the entire array as documentation mentions:

[image]
more info: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/15xeiac/how_to_update_an_item_in_an_array_with_firebase/

I could face a situation where both users stop the timer almost at the same time, and last one, would update the entire array with non updated timer from the other player, before getting it from database and some information can be overwritten.

`arrayUnion` adds a new element to the array, but doesn't update the one we have.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) to prevent two clients from overwriting each others' updates.  Your transaction will simply read the document to update, them make changes to it (by updating the array field, or anything else you want).  If two clients end up trying to run a transaction at the same time, one of them will be forced to automatically re-run your transaction handler to help you ensure that no data is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend this video on Firestore Arrays vs Subcollections:

**[Maps, Arrays and Subcollections, Oh My! | Get to know Cloud Firestore #4](https://youtu.be/o7d5Zeic63s?feature=shared&t=584)**

In short, the way that they work, you will always have this race condition sort of problem. The best approach for your use case is probably to just use a subcollection instead of an array. Arrays are really intended to be static objects like flags, and not a collection of dynamic data. You could use a transaction, but you may still have concurrency issues.

Comment: it makes sense and now I remember facing the same situation in the past and taking this approach. Only thing is that I have a stream (flutter) for this document to listen when a player makes any change. Would the stream work when the inner documents get updated?

Comment: Yes, it does. You just need to use a query onsnapshot  event rather than a document onsnapshot event.

Comment: Here is the documentation for that specifically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: Also, if the answer worked for you, don't forget to accept it to help out others in the future. :)

Comment: I'm trying to listen to the document and to its documents but so far I can only do once. I have game_sessions/players. I need to find a specific game_session:  _firestore
        .collection("game_sessions")
        .doc(gameSessionId)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.data();
      var docs = snapshot.docs; // doesn't work
    });
If I do .collection("game_sessions")
        .doc(gameSessionId)
        .collection("players")
        .snapshots() it won't listen to game_session document

Comment: I could have 2 listeners, but is it possible to listen to both (params and inner documents)

Comment: I believe that you have to have to have two listeners: one for the game session document and one for the players collection. The players collection listener will track the documents within that collection, but you still need one for the game session document, since it is a different collection.

Comment: hmmm in that case better to use another approach. The problem is that this would multiply by 2 all my reads to Firestore, affecting my quota limitation also. I will use an object this time

Comment: I added a comment with all the info. It works great now. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Nice! Great write up!

Answer (score 1):

Following @egeer comment I initially moved the array:

```
 players: [
  {
   id: string,
   time: int
  },
  {
   id: string,
   time: int
  } 
 ]
```

to its own colletion:

- `game_sessions/players/ID1`
- `game_sessions/players/ID2`

This was ok but, but I'd need an extra stream to listen to this other collection (because I was also listening to `game_sessions` params), which is totally fine, but since I'm on Spark (free) plan, this would affect my quota limitation, duplicating the number of reads to Firestore.

So I created instead an object with the different players ids moving from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

These are some methods updated:

```
Future<String> createGameSession() async {
    final user = AuthProvider().getUser();
    final sessionRef = await _firestore.collection('game_sessions').add({
      'created_by': user.uid,
      'status': 'open',
      'players': {
        user.uid: {
          'name': user.displayName,
          'avatar': user.photoURL,
        }
      }
    });
    gameSessionId = sessionRef.id;
    return sessionRef.id;
  }

Future<void> addPlayerGameSession() async {
    final user = AuthProvider().getUser();
    await _firestore.collection('game_sessions').doc(gameSessionId).update({
      'players.${user.uid}': {
        'name': user.displayName,
        'avatar': user.photoURL,
      }
    });
  }
```

I have access to these players with this:

```
data['players'].forEach((key, value) {
});
```

So I can update a specific element in an array (well, technically it's not an array, but works the same)